# Node / Postgres SQL Select distinct entries then put all other entries with the same reference into one column

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

this question was probably asked somewhere but I can't seem to phrase it correctly in the search to find an accurate answer.

I'm doing a query on a Postgres DB, it has quite a few joins, the results are something like this:

```
WON   |   name   |   item
1         Joe        A
1         Joe        B
2         Smith      A
```

So one row for each entry, I need to somehow get the result back as such:

```
WON   |   name   |   item
1         Joe        A, B
2         Smith      A
```

This can be done in the query or with NodeJS, there are hundreds to thousands of results for the query, so getting a distinct row (WON 1) then searching the DB for all entries that match it then repeating for the rest isn't feasible, so this may be better done in Node / Javascript, but I'm somewhat new to that, what would be a (somewhat) efficient way to do this?

If there IS a way to do this in the query itself then that would be my preference though.

Thanks

Comment: Just for the future. This is called string concatenation. Might help to solve similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY and [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) to cancat rows, somelike this:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
won int,
name character varying(255),
item character varying(255)
); 


insert into test (won, name, item) values (1,'Joe', 'A'),(1, 'Joe', 'B'),(2, 'Smith', 'A')
```

And do this in the query:

```
select won, name, string_agg(item, ',') from test group by won, name order by won
```

See this example in [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ab8c/27/0)

Answer (score 1):

A sql approach:

```
SELECT won, name
      ,STRING_AGG(item, ',' ORDER BY item) AS items
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY won, name
  ORDER BY won, name
```